# Magento 2: how to add child block in topnav

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks

How to add child block to catalog.topnav in magento2. in magento 1 we can do that like.

```
<reference name="catalog.topnav">
    <block type="core/template" name="main-menu" template="html/custommenu.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

The equivalent of your code in Magento 2 would be with double colon:

```
<referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="main-menu" template="Vendor_Module::html/custommenu.phtml" />
</referenceBlock>
```

Comment: no luck on that.. tried that .  `$this->getChildHtml('main-menu')`

Comment: @QaisarSatti Yeah that won't work you need to use `echo $block->getChildHtml('main-menu')`

Comment: off course i do that :D :D still not work for me..

Answer (score 2):

You can try with below code,

```
<referenceContainer name="page.top">
            <referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav">
                <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" name="theme_menu" template="Package_Module::html/topmenu.phtml" />
             </referenceBlock>
 </referenceContainer>
```

Comment: You can either use `referenceContainer` or `referenceBlock` - you don't need to use both, even though it should work. The answer of @Raphael was already good.

Comment: above solutions is works well.

Comment: @JisseReitsma is right even though the solution works. Using the only referenceBlock is all required.

Answer (score 0):

```
<referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="main-menu" template="Vendor_Module::html/custommenu.phtml" />
</referenceBlock>
```

In your phtml file you may need to use block

```
<?=$block->getChildBlock('main-menu')->toHtml() ?>
```